# Passing a python list to django template

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-errors

I want to display a list of things on my template. So I have a view to generate that list and pass it to template like this:

```
newlinks = []
try:
    links=urllib2.urlopen("<<Some HTML file link>>").readlines()
except (urllib2.HTTPError):
    links = ''
    pass
for link in links:
    newlinks.append(link[0:-1])                       
return render_to_response('template11.html', {'links',newlinks}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

But while rendering it, i get TypeError

```
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: unhashable type: 'list'
```

This is template code:

```
{% for link in links %}
    <li>{{ link }}</li>
{% endfor %}
```

I don't understand this error. Also if this approach is wrong(I think it is), then how would I pass a list to template?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In `return render_to_response()`, `{'links',newlinks}` is causing the error.  It should be `{'links': newlinks}`.

Answer (score 5):

And here is what you would put in the template11.html

```
<ul>
  {% for link in links %}
    <li>{{ link }}</li>
  {% endfor %} 
</ul>
```