# Problem passing list to a template Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'm trying to pass a list of books from views.py to a html template.

I took the datetime example and modified it but it's not working.

Here is my views.py:

```
def theBooks(request): 
    t = template.loader.get_template('templates/index.html')
    the_books = Book.objects.all()
    c = template.Context({'books': the_books})
    html = t.render(c)
    return HttpResponse(html)
```

And my template is:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="es">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Current Time</title>
 </head>
 <body>

    {# This is a comment #}

    {# check the existence of now variable in the template using if tag #}

  {% if now %}   
     <p>The books are: {{ books }}</p>
  {% else %}               
    <p>now variable is not available</p>
  {% endif %}

 </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: `{'books': the: books}` should be `{'books': the_books}`

Comment: I think similar questions asked before
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12761173/passing-a-python-list-to-django-template

Answer (score 1):

You have removed `now` from the context in your view, but you still have `{% if now %}` in your template. Change it to check `books` instead:

```
{% if books %}   
    <p>The books are: {{ books }}</p>
{% else %}               
    <p>There are no books</p>
{% endif %}
```

Note that you don't normally render templates like this in Django. Usually you would use the render shortcut and the view would look something like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def view_books(request): 
    books = Book.objects.all()
    context = {'books': books}
    return render(request, 'index.html', context)
```

Comment: Just copied and pasted your answer. Still not working.

Comment: "Not working" isn't enough information for us to help you debug the problem. If there are books in your database and your template is rendered with the context `{'books': the_books}`, then the template snippet above will display them.

Answer (score 0):

the 'The_books' is a list , which is also a iterator.

You may try add a loop to your code.

Please see my template code of my website:

```
{% for item in article %}
<div class="blog-post">

<h2>{{ item.title }}</h2>

<p style="font-size: 12pt;">
<a style="border: 2px solid black;color: black">&nbsp;{{ item.type }} </a>
<i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Posted by GYH on {{ item.data }} {{ item.time }}</i></p>

<a href="article/{{ item.id }}" class="btn btn-default btn-lg ">Read More <i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></a>
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

The article in my code just like your 'the_books' which is in the view.py , while in template , named books by you.

if you wan to show the item of the_books , try:

```
{% for book in books%}
    <a>book</a>
{% end for %}
```

By the way : the value in dict must equal to the value in html file.